# How to synchronize date, time and time zone between an android tablet and a Linux system?

Tags: android, linux, shell, adb

I am working with a Linux system that is connected to an Android tablet.  I need to synchronize the date, time and timezone.  I have software running on both and would like to correlate logcat messages from the Android tablet with log messages on the Linux system.  Both of which include a time stamp.

I have found that I can synchronize the date and time using this command.

```
adb shell date $(date +%s)
```

That does not set the TimeZone however.

I can get a numeric time zone using this command

```
date +%z
```

The software on my Linux system sets this offset using a list of UTC offsets (UTC-0700, UTC+0700, etc.) and a checkbox indicating if daylight savings is being observed.  If it is the offset is incremented by an hour.

**Update:** The software on my linux system compiles its own /etc/localtime file which contains the UTC offset and some binary data.

```
$ ll /etc/localtime
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 120 Jan 18 14:06 /etc/localtime
$ date
Wed Jan 23 13:05:37 -07 2019
```

Android requires a Region/City.

```
adb shell setprop persist.sys.timezone "America/Denver"
```

If I understand correctly this allows android to set the UTC offset and take into account this timezone's observation of daylight savings time.

For the time being I have created a switch statement in my shell script that maps each specified offset to a Region/City.  This is problematic as some of the offsets provided by the software on my linux system don't exist in the list of time zones found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

```
adb shell date $(date +%s)
timeZoneOffset=`date +%z`
case "$timeZoneOffset" in
    +1400)
        timeZone="Pacific/Kiritimati"
        ;;
...
    -1200)
        timeZone="Etc/GMT+12"
        ;;
    *)
        timeZone="Europe/London"
        ;;
esac
adb shell setprop persist.sys.timezone $timeZone
```

This script is run at startup and a restart is required when the software on the Linux system changes the timezone.  This works most of the time unless I picked a Region/City that observes (and happens to be observing) daylight savings time or no Region/City matches the offset I am given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the time zone on any *nix system is set by creating a symlink /etc/localtime to one of the zoneinfo files in /usr/share/zoneinfo/.  The files in zoneinfo are generally named things like Europe/London, so the command "readlink /etc/localtime | cut -d/ -f5-" would probably give you the correct timezone value unless something is handled differently on your system.  If that is the case, you may need to make/find some utility that can match up the selected timezone with the closest entry in the zoneinfo database.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like my system does handle the time zone differently.   Your answer helped me to know how it should be done though.  There doesn't seem to be a way to set a custom system time zone on android.

Comment: The android is running a linux kernel, so it shouldn't be impossible to duplicate your timezone info from your linux workstation.  It's just a matter of figuring out precisely what options it will accept for persist.sys.timezone.

Comment: ...or traversing the zoneinfo db to find the closest match.  I've seen a few systems where localtime isn't a symlink.  I'm not sure if it's an intentional change, a poorly designed tool for setting timezone, or what.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.  I don't see a /etc/localtime on my tablet though.  Looking at the documentation for [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setTimeZone(java.lang.String)) it appears that they only allow Olson time zones and I haven't found a way to add to their list of valid timezones.  In my app I can create a custom [TimeZone](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone) with the right offset, but I can't pass that TimeZone to the AlarmManager.  Setting the default time zone doesn't affect the logs in logcat.

Comment: it seems that my android phone doesn't have it either.  I guess that since they are mobile devices, a different method of handling timezones was patched in.  It sounds like you are going to have to pull a list of available settings from the tablet, try to match them up with your own zoneinfo db, and then find the one out of that set which has the same (or close) offset and dst settings.  Or just keep expanding your switch manually. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are solely interested in the date and time matching (like I am).  You can set the tablet's time zone to Etc/GMT and then manually apply the UTC offset like so.

```
adb shell setprop persist.sys.timezone "Etc/GMT"
tz=`date +%z`
sign=${tz:0:1}
hours=${tz:1:2}
minutes=${tz:3:2}
(( offset = (3600 * hours) + (60 * minutes) ))
t=`date +%s`
if [ $sign == "-"]
then
    (( t = t - offset ))
else
    (( t = t + offset ))
fi
adb shell date $t
```

The time zone will be wrong, but the date and time will be correct.